# Why can't (partially) packed arrays be used in this example?

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, packed-arrays

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier and persisting through 12.1 or later. Fixed in 13.0.0 or earlier**

---

I didn't expect any difference between these:

```
dsa = {{{#@{3}}}, {{#@{2, 2}}}} &[Developer`ToPackedArray];
dsa[[All, 1, 1, -1]] = q;
dsa
```

> {{{{q}}}, {{{q, 2}}}}

```
asd = {{{#@{3}}}, {{#@{2, 2}}}} &[Identity];
asd[[All, 1, 1, -1]] = q;
asd
```

> {{{{q}}}, {{{2, q}}}}

What makes the differences?

*Update:* I reported it for version 12.0 and got a response confirming it is a bug.

Comment: Must be a bug in the implementation of write access to nestes packed arrays. The analogous read operations `dsa[[All, 1, 1, -1]]` are performed correctly in both cases. I would suggest to report it to Wolfram Support.

Comment: Where is this difference coming from? What's the way to avoid it? This makes me nervous about my recent work's validity. Can we possibly find a work-around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug appears to have been fixed in `V13.0.0` or earlier

> [image: fixedbug]